# how to combine arrays on the similar key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

i have this situation `$test`:

```
               $months = Array
                    (
                        [3] => 7.56
                        [7] => 11.94
                        [1] => 6.90
                        [17] => 6.90
                        [6] => 6.90
                        [4] => 19.50
                    )
               $total = Array
                    (
                        [31] => 10
                        [17] => 4
                    )
```

i would like to combine them in such way that ill get `$x = array([17] => 6.90)`

basically put together the `values` from `$months` and the `keys` from `$total` where the `$months.key` = `$total.key`

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Can you further explain your desired result and the given problem? I'm having a hard time grasping what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($total as $k => $v) if (isset($months[$k])) $x[$k] = $months[$k];
```

Comment: True -- I assumed the OP would know that, this wasn't intended to make his code feature complete, it was intended to solve his question :)

Answer (score 2):

You should try array_intersect_keys ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php))

From the doc:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
    $array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

    var_dump(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2));
?>
```

output

```
array(2) {
  ["blue"]=>
  int(1)
  ["green"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

"array_intersect_key() returns an array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments."

So if you want always the "values" of the first array, this is solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = array();
foreach($total as $key => $value)
{
  if (array_key_exists($key, $months))
  {
    $x[$key] = $months[$key];
  }
}
```

Comment: This is more functionally correct than my solution, assuming 0 is a valid value for a month, a case which my example might not correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this may be a job for array merge.

```
$x = array_merge($months,$total);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php